# HP Pavilion X2 10 - Ubuntu 16.04 having no drivers

Tags: drivers, hp, hp-pavilion

I am using **HP Pavilion X2 10 (Detachable n182ng)**. On Windows 10 everything seems to work, while on Ubuntu 16.04 no hardware seems to be supported.

The touchpad doesn't recognize sliding, battery has no status, no auto rotation.

Where can I find the drivers, and how can I install them?

Software -> Additional drivers shows only one entry: "Unknown: Unknown Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs with intel microcode (prioprietary)"

Comment: Did you check: "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" ? What does it show?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions, one for each dysfunctional peace of hardware, and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: I do not have multiple questions, just clarifying the details.

Comment: You have multiple pieces of hardware that don't work, that cannot be covered by one question reasonably. You'll have far better chances of getting answers to each of them if you ask about them separately.

Comment: No, missing drivers to a particular model of laptop is one question, not matter how many hardware components it has.

Comment: There are no drivers for particular laptop models in Ubuntu. Drivers and settings are specific to devices.